# How do I apply two styles in the same line in LibreOffice?

Tags: styles, libreoffice-writer, openoffice-writer

**Problem:**

How do I apply two styles in the same line in LibreOffice?

The main problem is that I need two *different* styles:

- one for the index and
- one that is not supposed to appear in the index

**Example:**

> Table_name - author: john

In the index, I only want "table_name". The author should *not* appear in the index.

Comment: why the downvotes? if you don't know the answer do not blame me.

Comment: For what it's worth, your question was hard to understand. I tried to reword it and hope it makes more sense now.

Comment: thank you. I found a solution with tables, but is not very functional.

Comment: I've added an answer regarding general indexes (alphabetic index). Does this fit your needs? You're writing about a table - is your question specific to creating an **index of tables** based on the **table captions**? This would require a different solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that there are two different issues combined in this question:

- Restricting an index entry to a single word, not the complete paragraph;
- Applying different styles in the same paragraph;

To restrict an index entry to a single word, just double-click that word and select (from Menu `Insert`) `Indexes and Tables` -> `Entry`. In the following dialogue, you can select if the word should appear in the TOC, the alphabetical index, or in a user-defined index.

Applying different styles can be done using **[character styles](http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/OOoAuthors_User_Manual/Writer_Guide/Using_character_styles)** for the index entries.

[image: Character Styles Window]

After creating a character style for those entries (in my screenshot: "*Indexed Word*"), you will have to assign it manually to the words marked as index entries. To navigate between those entries, you can use the navigation window,

[image: "Open Navigation" Button]

selecting `index entries` as navigation object:

[image: Navigation Window]