# Can I define a paragraph so it contains different styles?

Tags: styles, libreoffice-writer

I am writing a play and almost all my paragraphs are constructed the same way. Here are examples of two paragraphs whose styles are called "Blocking" and "Line".

```
(Blocking)

CHARACTER NAME → Line of texte that can
                 be on more than one
                 line.
```

What I would like to do is:

- Detect where first the tabulation (→) is in a "Line" paragraph and set the style of the text before it as ALL-CAPS.
- Automatically add an opening and a closing paretheisis in a "Blocking" paragraph.

Is it possible to do so in any way?

---

**EDIT**

I am aware of character styles. What I'd like to find out is "How can I add one automatically?

Exemple: everything before the → gets the "Name" style.

Comment: CSS proposes a *:before* and *:after* pseudo-classes, it may have been implemented in some way. Any ideas?

Comment: See [this answer.](http://superuser.com/a/340339/64294) It describes how to use different styles by word **and** within a paragraph. I'm not sure if it will be useful to you, as it is more table based, and you're using text in an unfamiliar way to me. I don't know much about this, so no criticism intended!

Comment: @FeralOink: thanks for the comment. I see no criticism in it. It will help me edit my question, thanks.